# Creating a series of Folders in sdcard android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My require file in sd card has path

```
Android/data/mypakagename/android/myfile/abc/myfile.txt
```

i have a url from where i will download this myFile.txt and place it in this location. 
Right now I have directory `Android/data/mypakagename/` created in sdCard.

Now i am using following code.

```
File file = new File("Android/data/mypakagename/android/myfile/abc/myfile.txt
");
file.mkdirs();
```

This creates all folders however it also create myfile.txt as a folder.I want to create all missing directories except last one. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    File file = new File("Android/data/mypakagename/android/myfile/abc/myfile.txt
");
    File parent = file.getParentFile();
    parent.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String filename = "myfile.txt"
File dir = new File ("Android/data/mypakagename/android/myfile/abc");  
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, filename);
```